# Emacs, gdb: How do direct program output to gdb buffer in gdb 2 window mode

Tags: emacs, gdb

Is there a way to tell Emacs 24.3.1 with gdb 7.5 to display the program output in the gdb buffer instead of a separate "** input/output **" buffer?

(Displaying it in a separate buffer in 2 window gdb mode really messes up the current windows and I then need to go searching for the gdb and source windows again. Text only terminal, so no multi-windows mode.)